# What is the correct place to use the @transaction.atomic decorator?

Tags: django, transactions

In my Django apps, the first database operation that I want to wrap in a transaction might occur at any level of the framework -- it could be in the view, a manager method, or a model method.

Up until now, my practice has been to mark the *outermost method* where database write access first occurs with `@transaction.atomic`. But I'm finding this painful to keep track of.  As I refactor or move things around, the outermost method frequently changes.  What is the best way to handle this?

Here are some options I'm considering, and of course I'm open to any other suggestions.

### Option 1: The view method only.

Should I just always declare `@transaction.atomic` at the view level and be done with it?

```
@transaction.atomic
def view_method():
    # database operation
    manager_method()

def manager_method():
    # database operation
    model_method()

def model_method():
    # database operation
    another_model_method()

def another_model_method():
    # database operation
```

### Option 2: All of the methods.

Or should I wrap every method that leads to multiple database operations?

```
@transaction.atomic
def view_method():
    # database operation
    manager_method()

@transaction.atomic(savepoint=False)
def manager_method():
    # database operation
    model_method()

@transaction.atomic(savepoint=False)    
def model_method():
    # database operation
    another_model_method()

def another_model_method():
    # database operation
```

### Option 3: Only the methods I expect will be called externally.

Or should I declare `@transaction.atomic` only on methods that are part of the app's external API?  Here, for example, I expect `model_method()` to also be called from a script, or the admin interface, etc.

```
@transaction.atomic
def view_method():
    # database operation
    manager_method()

def manager_method():
    # database operation
    model_method()

@transaction.atomic(savepoint=False)    
def model_method():
    # database operation
    another_model_method()

def another_model_method():
    # database operation
```

This option seems the most "correct"... but it perpetuates my issue.  The external API might change as I refactor and rewrite the app and this also forces me to guess about how the application might be used in the future, which I may not know at this point.

What is the standard way of handling this?

Comment: Correct way is to set it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#atomic-requests

Comment: @AndreyShipilov The second line of "The Zen of Python" says "Explicit is better than implicit." https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Answer (score 1):

The common rule is to wrap outermost function/method, in case of Django it must be controller function/method.

However, depending on your business logic you can have nested savepoints (each nested `transaction.atomic` simply creates savepoint) where you want more granular control of what to commit or rollback. In this case any other inner function can be wrapped with `transaction.atomic`.

Also, it is not recommended to use ATOMIC_REQUESTS (explained here in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests))